# Use UITabbarController with pushViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

Let say in the UITabbarController we have tab A,B,C.

When user goes to tab C from tab A, the navigationController of tab C push a new view on top of it by either using 
1) pushViewController = new view ; or
2) addSubView(new view)

After that, when user left tab C, either go to tab A or B. After that again, if user goes back to tab C, which view they are going to see in tab C? What are the results based on the 2 different situations above?

Comment: If you are loading the view of tab C for the first time it will show the the first view you have set on that tab, but once your TAB C view is initialized you navigate to some other view in tab c only change the tab to A or B and come back to C you will have the same screen on TAB C from where you left it.

Comment: @spider1983 according your experience you have any idea why my code does not work like that? The code is too long, hard to paste here...

Comment: it may happens that on the exit of your current tab you are popping your view to its root view... in your case check if you are popping your TAB C view to root View i am considering that you have separate navigation controller for your every TAB ie A,B, C

Comment: @spider1983 Yes all my tab A, B, C is navigation controller. You mean I should check those exiting function like ViewWillDisappear or ViewDidDisappear (name might not be correct), something like that?

Comment: Do your TABS A,B,C have common navigationcontroller or seperate???

Comment: @spider1983 they are separated as [[UINavigationController alloc] iniWithRootViewController:S];  , S is a UIViewController. I did this 3 times for A, B, C UIViewController.

Comment: ok then please check your code if anywhere it is written to pop the view to rootview if you change the tab...coz whatever condition you said your code should work as stated in above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have separate navigation controllers for each of your tabs, as I would do, then you will see the new view in both cases after the user returns to tab C. In the event that the user touches the tab C tab again then the navigation controller will pull back the pushed views (or their controllers respectively) to the first one on the stack. That applies to case 1) only. Nothing would happen in case 2).

Comment: Hi, I can't fully understand this >" In the event that the user touches the tab C tab again then the navigation controller will pull back the pushed views (or their controllers respectively) to the first one on the stack. That applies to case 1) only. Nothing would happen in case 2)."

Comment: What does it mean "user touches the tab C tab again"? Does it mean user tab on c tab while he is currently viewing c tab? Or he switch to c tab from other tab?

Comment: Yes, it means that tab c is currently visible and the user touches it again on the tab bar. In that case the default behaviour is that the tab view is "reset" to its very own root view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Add subview is used to add any subview to the current view so in both the cases u will get the  same view showing but if you add a "new view" view controller using AddSubView then in this case the control will not go to the .m file of the new view and you will not be able to interact with the UIControls of the "new View" using .h and .m file of "new view".

If you want to do something on the "new view" for example using some UIButton or UITextField then you would have to write code for that in the .h and .m file of the view controller on which you added "new view" as a subview.